# Subring such that all products are zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose I have a ring $R$, and I want to find a subset $J \subset R$ such that 
$$xy = 0 : x,y \in J$$
(and hopefully, find the 'maximal' such subset $J$). Is there a name for such subsets $J$, or are they all just trivial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $R=\mathbb{Z}/4$, represented by $0,1,2,3$. Then $J=\{0,2\}$ is such a set. The sets
$$
\mathrm {Ann} _{R}(S)=\{r\in R\mid \forall s\in S,rs=0\}
$$
are called (left) annihilator sets.